# Is it possible to change the priority of a swapfile without turning it off?

Tags: linux, swap

I have two large swapfiles, each about 500 GB in size, and a program that is using about 900 GB of the total 1 TB of swap space. The memory-hungry program will take a few days to finish. However, I just realized that the swapfile priorities are incorrect. `swapon` says:

```
NAME                TYPE        SIZE   USED PRIO
/dev/sda            partition 465,8G 465,8G   -1
/home/alex/swapfile file      502,9G 384,5G   -2
```

`/home/alex/swapfile` is on an M.2 disk capable of 3.5 GB/s, whereas `/dev/sda` is a SATA disk capable of only 540 MB/s. So, I want `/home/alex/swapfile` to have priority `-1` and `/dev/sda` to have priority `-2`, but I really don't want to interrupt the long-running process. Is there any way to change the swapfile priorities without first disabling the swapfile with `swapoff`?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do that with a live existing swapfile -- however, you can create another swapfile with an even higher priority of 0 or 1 that's on the fast disk (assuming you have space on /home/alex still).

Create it with `dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile2 bs=1M count=$SIZE_IN_MEGS`. (Your 500 gig swapfile is huge btw.)

You could then swapoff the first /home/alex/swapfile, but there's no point as it's on the same disk as the new /home/alex/swapfile2 - it'll only be used to swap in (and not out) until swapfile2 (and /dev/sda) are full. You could swapoff /dev/sda as well but you'll suffer the speed penalty of it til it's all read back in - and if you are low on ram, swapped back out to swapfile2.

This might be useful to you if you continue to operate with low ram and can do this at some point you don't need performance for the time it takes to swap back in and out, then to return later with the swapped ram in swapfile2, which will operate much faster from then on.

Comment: Even better to use `fallocate` instead of `dd`

Answer (score -2):

No need to re-create the swap file. You can simply specify the priority in /etc/fstab, such as:

/mnt/ssd/swapfile none  swap sw,pri=5  0 0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).